# Read ArrayList into ObservableList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

Still learning the ropes and I've used a mix mash of code snippets and a bit of my own work to make this, what I've gotten stuck at is how to read back a file I've stored.

Inside my main class i have used ObservableList of which I convert to A ArrayList after which I use FileOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream,

I would like to be able to "load" the data back in via FileInputStream and ObjectInputStream.

I used [This to help me save the data but can't work out how to read it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794995/how-to-serialize-observablelist).

Or if you can think of a alternative method to do what I'm after that would be swell.

My Main

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXGUI extends Application {

Stage window;

TableView<Product> table;
TextField nameInput, priceInput, quantityInput;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("thenewboston - JavaFX");

    //Name column
    TableColumn<Product, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameColumn.setMinWidth(200);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    //Price column
    TableColumn<Product, Double> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Price");
    priceColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));

    //Quantity column
    TableColumn<Product, String> quantityColumn = new TableColumn<>("Quantity");
    quantityColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));

    //Name input
    nameInput = new TextField();
    nameInput.setPromptText("Name");
    nameInput.setMinWidth(100);

    //Price input
    priceInput = new TextField();
    priceInput.setPromptText("Price");

    //Quantity input
    quantityInput = new TextField();
    quantityInput.setPromptText("Quantity");

    //Button
    Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(e -> addButtonClicked());
    Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete");
    deleteButton.setOnAction(e -> deleteButtonClicked());

    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    hBox.setSpacing(10);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, priceInput, quantityInput, addButton, deleteButton);

    table = new TableView<>();
    table.setItems(getProduct());
    table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, priceColumn, quantityColumn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 400, 350);
    scene.setFill(Color.OLDLACE);

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

    // --- Menu File
    Menu menuFile = new Menu("File");
    MenuItem save = new MenuItem("Save...");
    menuFile.getItems().add(save);
    save.setOnAction(e -> {
        write(getProduct());
        System.out.println("Saved File");
    });

    // --- Menu Edit
    Menu menuEdit = new Menu("Edit");

    // --- Menu View
    Menu menuView = new Menu("View");

    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuFile, menuEdit, menuView);

    ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(menuBar, table, hBox);

    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();
}

//Add button clicked
public void addButtonClicked() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName(nameInput.getText());
    product.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(priceInput.getText()));
    product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(quantityInput.getText()));
    table.getItems().add(product);
    nameInput.clear();
    priceInput.clear();
    quantityInput.clear();
}

//Delete button clicked
public void deleteButtonClicked() {
    ObservableList<Product> productSelected, allProducts;
    allProducts = table.getItems();
    productSelected = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

    productSelected.forEach(allProducts::remove);
}

//Get all of the products
public ObservableList<Product> getProduct() {
    ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    products.add(new Product("Laptop", 859.00, 20));
    products.add(new Product("Bouncy Ball", 2.49, 198));
    products.add(new Product("Toilet", 99.00, 74));
    products.add(new Product("The Notebook DVD", 19.99, 12));
    products.add(new Product("Corn", 1.49, 856));
    return products;
}

public void write(ObservableList<Product> productObservalble) {
    try {
        // write object to file
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Objectsavefile.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(new ArrayList<Product>(productObservalble));
        oos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Products.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Product implements Serializable {

private String name;
private double price;
private int quantity;

/**
 * Create Constructor with empty data
 */
public Product() {
    this.name = "";
    this.price = 0;
    this.quantity = 0;
}

/**
 *
 * @param name - Set the name for the Product
 * @param price - Set the price of said Product
 * @param quantity - Set how many of said product
 */
public Product(String name, double price, int quantity) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

/**
 * Get the name of a Product
 *
 * @return
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * Set the name of a Product
 *
 * @param name
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Get the price of a Product
 *
 * @return
 */
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

/**
 * Set the price of a Product
 *
 * @param price
 */
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

/**
 * Get the quantity of a Product
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

/**
 * Set the quantity of a Product
 *
 * @param quantity
 */
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product [Name=" + name + ", Price=" + price + ", quantity="
            + quantity + "]";

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the opposite:

```
public ObservableList<Product> read() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(...));
    List<Product> list = (List<Product>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

}
```