# JavaFX: How can I save my ObservableList to file and then load?

Tags: javafx

I have an `ObservableList<Person>` and class `Person` with 4 properties.

How can I save this list to file and next load when the program next time starts?

Properties doesn't implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize ObservableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794995/how-to-serialize-observablelist)

Comment: You have answer for your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34795127/7236804