# Cyclic Object Exception on JSON.stringify when with RxJs Subject in a class

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting a Cyclic Object Exception error while using serialize a class which happens to have a Rxjs Subject. If I subscribe in the class to the subject I will get a Cyclic Object Exception when I try to stringify. My sample class this ...

```
export class ThingToStringIfy
{
  private someProp : string;
  private aSubject = new Subject();

   constructor() {
     this.aSubject.subscribe();
}
```

}

So my question is am I using the subject incorrectly in some way, or did I happen to find a bug.  I'm currently just planning on using the JSON replacer function or something like circular-json-es6. Any suggestions on workarounds or improvements would be greatly appreciated. If it is a bug, I'd like to be a good citizen and actually report it.

Thanks

Here is a link to the offending code: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpfsuu?embed=1&file=app/hello.component.ts

Comment: What are you trying to stringify? Why are you stringifying it?

Comment: Here is a similar post considering serialization of observables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794995/how-to-serialize-observablelist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally neither observables nor private members aren't supposed to be serialized. This results in polluting serialized object with properties that shouldn't be there.

One way is to make private TypeScript properties concealed (non-enumerable) in JS output. This can be achieved with a decorator:

```
function Private() {
  return function (target: any, prop: string, descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor) {
    if (descriptor) {
      // method
      descriptor.enumerable = false;
    } else {
      // property initializer
      let propSymbol = Symbol(prop);

      Object.defineProperty(target, prop, {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        get() { return this[propSymbol] },
        set(value) { this[propSymbol] = value }
      });
    }
  };
}

export class ThingToStringIfy {
  @Private() private someProp : string;
  @Private() private aSubject = new Subject();
  ...
}
```

The decorator makes `private` properties excluded in `JSON.stringify` and other places where only own enumerable properties are expected.

Another way is to implement [`toJSON` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) that will be used by `JSON.stringify` instead of default routine:

```
export class ThingToStringIfy {
  private someProp : string;
  private aSubject = new Subject();
  ...
  toJSON() {
    const publicThis = Object.assign({}, this);
    // or lodash.omit or any alternative
    delete publicThis['someProp'];
    delete publicThis['aSubject'];
    return publicThis;
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice.. the only thing I had to change was add the @ in front of the Private